# Кем был Отелло?

Tags: литература

Всем известно, что шекспировский Отелло был мавром - так написано у классика. При этом, все постановки "Отелло", которые я знаю, изображают его чернокожим. Однако опять же мы знаем, что мавры - это не негры, а арабы, которые, хоть и смуглые, но отнюдь не чернокожие.
Так все-таки, кто ошибается: режиссеры, ставящие пьесу, или ошибался сам Шекспир, путая негров и арабов?
И еще один вопрос: сами имя "Отелло" вымышленное или реально существующее?

На фото - Отелло в исполнении Бондарчука:
[image]

Comment: Вылитый Федя... Вылитый!  
![ФБ](http://vokrug.tv/pic/news/f/1/0/9/f10991eeeed5dfda3e52c1951a8c6ea0.jpeg)

Answer (score 1):

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/28598389

"Реальный прототип литературной трагедии — итальянец по имени Маурицио Отелло. Он командовал венецианскими войсками на Кипре с 1505 по 1508 годы Киприоты полагают, что с национальностью главного героя Шекспир напутал. И в Венеции, и на Кипре, и во всей тогдашней Европе мавров не считали полноценными людьми и вряд ли стали бы доверять им командование флотом.

Ключ к разгадке кроется в имени ревнивца. Уменьшительный вариант имени Маурицио звучит как «Мауро» . А ещё это слово означает «мавр» по-итальянски. Видимо, поэтому Шекспир решил причислить своего героя к народу, населявшему тогда южное побережье Средиземного моря. Ошибку Шекспира усугубили театральные режиссёры, сделавшие Отелло негром, каковым он и по сей день выходит на сцену".

А вообще говоря, сюжеты Шекспира не отличаются простотой и изяществом, но это мое личное мнение. А Вам нравится "Отелло"?

Comment: Почему  бы  не  доверили ?  Он  же  крещёный  был.  И  кондотьер  к  тому  же.